# Why cscope don't search definitions in header files?

Tags: vim, cscope

I use the following command to generate my cscope database:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
find dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ -type f -regex ".*\.\([chlysS]\(xx\|pp\)*\|cc\|hh\|inl\|inc\|ld\)$" -print > $tmpfile
cscope -q -b -U -i $tmpfile -f cscope.out
```

Into vim, a `:cs f g myfunction` only leads me to the definition in C file, and nether in header file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got the terminology right. In C, usually the function *definitions* are put in C files, whereas *declarations* go into header files.

The cscope command f g (find *definition*) should correctly take you to the function *definition*. In the case where you actually have definitions in a header file (for example inline functions) the find definition command takes you there as well. If this is not the case, you should file a bug report to the cscope team.

Cscope unfortunately does not provide functionality for showing only a *declaration*. You could use the find symbol command (f s) but this might show a lot of results if the function is called from many places in your code.

You can use ctags which usually lets you choose from the declaration or definition. I usually use a mix of cscope and ctags within my projects because neither of them provides *all* the functionality i want.