# cscope not finding functions defined in header file in C

Tags: c, vim, ctags, cscope

I use cscope to browse the code.
For inline functions defined in the header file, I am getting error `E257: cstag: tag not found`.
Is there any way to include the header defined functions as well in the ctags?

The questions is already asked [Why cscope don't search definitions in header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697765/why-cscope-dont-search-definitions-in-header-files) but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: If you are using `:cstag` it means that you are using both cscope and ctags. Did you consider indexing your headers with ctags?

Comment: How do I do that? @romainl